# Nodejs - Proxy multiple applications to a single url locally

Tags: node.js, proxy

I'd like to have multiple nodejs applications all listening on different ports proxied to a URL on my local machine.

An example would be

localhost:3000 -> mysite.dev
localhost:3030 -> mysite.dev/api

It would make developing locally match my production setup and help immensely with my stateless authentication setep. I thought [hotel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hotel) was going to be the solution I wanted, but it doesn't do exactly what I'm looking for.

If possible I'd like to avoid using nginx locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `http-proxy` module and you can specify proxy as

```
var http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
//
// Create your proxy server and set the target in the options.
//
httpProxy.createProxyServer({target:'http://localhost:9000'}).listen(8000); // See (†)

//
// Create your target server
//
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.write('request successfully proxied!' + '\n' + JSON.stringify(req.headers, true, 2));
  res.end();
}).listen(9000);
```

they have nice docs available here https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy

Comment: That's great, thank you.  This is just what I'm looking for.

Comment: Could you put up an example that answers the question which includes 2 separate proxies on port 80 separated by the URI?