# Run two app on same server or on same port

Tags: node.js, angular, express, proxy, mean

I have MEAN stack apps, I want a suggestion about to run both them on the same server or on the same port(suggestion which one is better).I found article about to run server on the same port using proxies,also I want to know is this a good idea.There is some troubles about running on same server,because I'm using Angular 6 as Front-end, I have to build those files into my node's (which is one in this case) public folder,so I think that's impossible (I think), because there must be index.html and it must be one and not only index.html, other files too. And if this two cases is not good deal.please just let me know about that.Thanks for help and thanks for attention.

Comment: You can't run the two express apps on the same port. Instead what you can do is, run nginx server, and configure it to reverse proxy requests to your servers based on route. This way, you will have same endpoint for accessing both express apps. You just need to specify routes for which app to access. ex: localhost:80/app1 points to localhost:8000 and localhost:80/app2 points to localhost:8001

Comment: Akshay Milmile, here is the article that I talked about.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134363/nodejs-proxy-multiple-applications-to-a-single-url-locally

Comment: I still think to achieve what you want do, you should prefer nginx.

Comment: Ok, thanks Akshay Milmile I'll try that way.